# run python script in parallel to matlab

Tags: python, matlab, parallel-processing

I have 2 scripts:

1. python script
2. matlab script

I need to run this two scripts in parallel (no output for both of them). I was thinknig to call to the  python scirpt, from the matlab script.

I know it is possible to run python script from matlab like:

```
systemCommand='my_script.py'
system(systemCommand)
```

however in this way, the matlab script will wait to the return of the python script, and the rest of my matlab script will not be executed.

any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried appending an ampersand (`&`) to the end of your system command to send it to the background? (`'my_script.py &'`)

Comment: I tried now and it works! thanks!

Comment: I have gone ahead and added it as a format answer. Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned near the end of MATLAB's [`system` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) in the "Tips" section, to run a system command in the background (on *nix), you can append an ampersand(`&`) to the end of your command to tell it to run in the background.

```
system('my_script.py &')
```

If you're on Windows, you'll want to use the following to prevent a command window from opening.

```
system('start /b my_script.py');
```

Comment: Do you know how can I close the cmd that opens for the python script after I have finished using it?

Comment: At the end of your python script, do you have `sys.exit(0)`?

Comment: What Operating System?

Comment: Windows. did I understand you right? I have jest added the comad to the end of my code?

Comment: @TomE8 I just edited my question to include a Windows-specific answer. Try that one out.

Comment: I have tried it. It opens a new cmd window... I saw on: [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx) that the command you worte suppoze to be the right one... any ather ideas? thanks, Tom

Comment: @TomE8 Only other idea I have is possibly changing the extension of your python script to be ".pyw" which will use the pythonw.exe interpreter which shouldn't launch a window.